# When defining a python class, how to set a random variable in it?

Tags: python, class, random

Say I have a class called `Person`, which will have only the person's name and gender.

The gender should be randomly selected from Male and Female. To do that, I import the `random.randint()` function. The random gender is determined according to the random int.

```
import random

class Person:
    alias = random.randint(1, 3)
    if alias == 2:
        gender = 'Male'
    else:
        gender = 'Female'

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

r = Person('rachel')
s = Person('Stanky')
print(r.gender)
print(s.gender)
```

However, the result I get for different person from this class all have the same gender. My understanding is the `randint` is fixed once been generated. My question is how to make it different for each class instance.

Comment: Code on the top level of the class is run only once (at import time). If you want to make the choice for every instance put the code in the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your never getting a different gender is because the gender attribute is a *class* variable. Once Python creates your class object `Person`, the value of `gender` is never computed again. You need to make the `gender` variable an *instance* attribute. That means the gender will be computed on a per instance basis, instead of per class definition. eg:

```
import random

class Person:
  def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name
      alias= random.randint(1, 3)
      if alias == 2:
          self.gender = 'Male'
      else:
          self.gender = 'Female'

r= Person('rachel')
s= Person('Stanky')

print(r.gender) 
print(s.gender)
```

Which outputs

```
Female
Male
```

On a side note, I think a much better choice for your task would be to use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to select a random gender from a list of genders(male or female):

```
from random import choice

class Person:
  genders = ('Male', 'Female', 'Female')
  def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name
      self.gender = choice(Person.genders)

rachel = Person('Rachel')
stanky = Person('Stanky')

print(rachel.gender) 
print(stanky.gender)
```

Notice in my example above, `Person.genders` *is* a class variable. This is on purpose. Because we only need to create a list of genders *once*, we can make the list a class level variable.

Comment: One other thing worth mentioning: this can be made a lot simpler using `self.gender = random.choice(['Male', 'Female'])`.

Comment: @Mac I was just about to add an edit saying the exact same thing. Great minds think alive, eh? ;-)

Comment: you should definetly put the `choice` approach at the top. That's the right way to solve the problem!

Comment: @MSeifert While I most certainly agree, it seems to me that it would be better to answers the OP's _original_ question first(see this [meta discussion for more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349138/should-i-stop-including-useful-tips-with-my-answers)). But your right, I'll add a comment saying the using the `choice` method is a better way.

Comment: You're right. It could also be intended that the female to male ratio is 2:1 (`randint` includes end points). In that case the `choice` approach needs to be `choice(['male', 'female', 'female'])`... Better to have `randint` at the top as long as the intention isn't clearly stated.

Comment: @Noob. Use two backticks (``) around your code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you already guessed the reason correctly why the gender doesn't change. To solve this you could use a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) for `gender`:

```
import random

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def gender(self):
        try:
            # If it has been defined for the instance, simply return the gender
            return self._gender
        except AttributeError:
            # If it's not defined yet, define it, and then return it
            self._gender = random.choice(['male', 'female'])
            return self._gender

r = Person('rachel')
s = Person('Stanky')
print(r.gender)
print(s.gender)
```

Comment: is this different with : `def __init__(self, name): self.name = name self.gender = random.choice(['Male','Female']) `?    Cuz what I see here is if no gender variable is declared, then we declare a new gender variable. However, this class only have a variable, which is name. That means no gender local variable will be defined for sure, isn't it?

Comment: You're right, it is different. The `_gender` variable is undefined as long as you don't access the property `gender`. But as soon as you access the property it will be defined. So it's a different implementation but for most purposes it will behave exactly like the `__init__` solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You should put random gender generation under `__init__`, so that it would be randomly generated for each class instance.

```
import random

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        alias= random.randint(1, 3)
        if alias == 2:
            self.gender = 'Male'
        else:
            self.gender = 'Female'

r= Person('rachel')
s= Person('Stanky')
print(r.gender)
print(s.gender)
```

Three times of results:

```
$ python classRandom.py 
Male
Female
$ python classRandom.py 
Female
Female
$ python classRandom.py 
Female
Male
```

Answer (score 0):

The gender variable is currently a class variable, that's why it stays the same for all the instance created. You will need to change them into a instance's attribute.

Side note: `random.randint(1, 3)` will either return 1, 2 or 3 not just 1 or 2. It is not the same as indexing, in which the ending is ignored. Right now, there's a higher chance to be a Female since it could be 1 or 3, so `random.randint(1,2)` makes more sense. I mentioned this just in case it was not done on purpose. You can also use `random.choice`, which will choose a random selection from a list.

```
import random

class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.gender= random.choice(["Male", "Female"]) # or random.choice(["Male", "Female", "Female"]) if you want a higher chance of being a female

r= Person('rachel')
s= Person('Stanky')
print(r.gender)
print(s.gender)
```