# A constructor for dataclasses with randomized attribute values

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Hi could someone explain whats happening here:
i want to instantiate objects with random values.

```
@dataclass
class Particle:
    pos = (random.randint(0, 800), random.randint(0, 800))

for _ in range(3):
    p = Particle()
    print(p.pos)
```

prints:

- (123, 586)
- (123, 586)
- (123, 586)

expected behaviour wold be three tuples with different values. Whats happening here??

(when i use a normal class it works as expected)

Comment: Removing the `@dataclass` doesn't fix your issue...  Related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991548/when-defining-a-python-class-how-to-set-a-random-variable-in-it) and [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466588/generating-random-number-for-class-attribute)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating the random integers only once at class definition. What you want is a default factory for your value.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field for more details.

Example:

```
def rndints():
    return (random.randint(0, 800), random.randint(0, 800))

@dataclass
class Particle:
    pos = field(default_factory=rndints)
```